# Npgsql and PostgreSQL timezones issue

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Warning: This software is kinda antique (PostgreSQL 10, Npgsql 2) but I intend to test it against the newer software.

The database timezone from postgresql.cof is 'GMT'.
The Windows timezone is Ukraine.

I'd like to save datatime with unspecified kind to column with timestamptz.

Will Npgsql convert the datetime to UTC from server(GMT) or from Windows(Ukraine) time zone?

I don't know why it's been installed as GMT because when I install it again, it uses my local time zone.

I'm asking because I have a few hours shift in tables that was populated with datetime unspecified kind.

Comment: A `timestamptz` field will always have its values stored in `UTC` which for practical purposes is equal to `GMT`.  For a more detailed explanation see [Datetimes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-datetime.html) Section *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps*.

Comment: I know. What happen if I do: new DateTime(2023, 5, 16, 5, 35) and save it in database to timestamptz field? Will it be converted to UTC from local windows timezone(Ukraine) or from 'timezone' setting(GMT) in postgresql.conf?

Comment: DateTime(2023, 5, 16, 5, 35, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecifed)

Comment: That is why I pointed you at the docs page and section, it steps you through exactly how the conversion is done. Rather then repeating the docs go to the link provided.

Comment: I really, really recommend upgrading to a new Npgsql version. There have been some serious changes in this specific area, to make the behavior more sane.

Comment: Note that the PG type that best corresponds to an Unspecified .NET DateTime is `timestamp without time zone`; `timestamp with time zone` implies that the timestamp is in UTC, as mentioned above. The latest versions of Npgsql enforce this.